# C++ Read from stdin if within size

Tags: c++

I want to read from stdin if that is within a size. How do I restrict that in this code?

```
std::cout << "Enter a string till end of line: " << std::endl;
std::isstreambuf_iterator<char> begin(std::cin), end;
std::string str(begin, end);
```

What I want is to restrict the read from stdin to maximum length of 10. If it is, then I would assign it to `string str`. Please help!

Comment: See if [`iostream::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) helps out.

Comment: Or maybe not. I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. What do you want done if the input is rejected? Discard it or preserve it for processing with a different set of rules?

Comment: I do not care if it is longer than the limit. I store *only if* the string is within length.

Comment: And that which you don't store can be safely discarded?

Comment: Yes, it can be discarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to read char-by-char from cin. Use functions:

```
cin.get(...)
```

or

```
char c;
cin >> c;
```

By this way you would control length and end-of-line.

Comment: Or look at [`std::istream::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline), which has a `count` parameter to limit input.

Answer (score 1):

Read a line. Make sure it's not too big. Use the line.

Example:

```cpp
std::cout << "Enter a string till end of line: " << std::endl;
std::string line;
if std::getline(std::cin, line)) // read in until end of line or end of stream
{
    if (line.size <= maximum_size) // ensure line isn't too big
    {
        // process line here
    }
}
else // read failed
{ 
    // May need some clean-up to handle failed input stream
}
```